# Git - how to merge feature branch, but exclude some commits?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch, rebase

I'm using Git for a long time now, but today I ran into a problem with merging some changes from branch to branch. This situation I'm having is - I got 4 branches: 2 main ones and 2 feature ones. Let's assume they're called like this: `main_branch1`, `main_branch2`, `feature_branch1` and `feature_branch2`. Feature branches are always created from `main_branch1` and when you finish your work, you merge them back into it. Then at some point of a time their changes are merged to `main_branch2` as well. There are no merges between two main branches!
Here goes the problem. In my case right now, `feature_branch1` is created from `main_branch1` at some time, did some changes inside of it and merged it back into the main branch. Then I created `feature_branch2` again from `main_branch1`, did changes there as well and also merged it back into it. Now I want to merge `feature_branch2` into `main_branch2`, but just the changes that it has - because when I created it I got the changes from `feature_branch1`. I tried with `git rebase`, but couldn't get the things going and my working tree looked like a complete mess.

Here is a graph of what I want to achieve and how my tree should look like:

```
o---------------o---------------------o  main_branch1
 \             / \                   /
  o-----------o   \                 /
feature_branch1    \               /
                    \             /
                     o-----------o
                  feature_branch2 \
                                   \
                                    o-----------o  main_branch2
```

As you can see when I created `feature_branch2`, I already got changes from `feature_branch1`, which were merged into `main_branch1`. How i can exclude them when I merge `feature_branch2` to `main_branch2`? But I will need to add them later on when I decide to merge `feature_branch1` into `main_branch2`...

Any idea how I can do that? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude the changes from `feature_branch1` then you'll need to checkout a new branch from before it was created and cherry pick the commits from `feature_branch2` then you'll be able to fully merge later.

```
git checkout -b nofeature1 <SHA before feature_branch1>
git cherry-pick <first SHA feature_branch2>^..feature_branch2
git checkout main_branch2
git merge nofeature1
```

Comment: So I need to create a new branch without the changes from `feature_branch1` every time I do a merge to `main_branch2`?

Comment: @nogravity If you're starting point is on `main_branch1` then yes because it has `feature_branch1` in its history. I think it would be better to create a new base branch without `feature_branch1` in its history. Otherwise you're going to be continuously merging back into `main_branch1` then you would presumably want all the other changes too, so that would look like `git cherry-pick <SHA of merge feature_branch1 into main_branch1>..main_branch1` every time.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in to `rebase --onto` - it lets you rebase, but gives you a little more control over the specific commits involved.

`git rebase --onto <new_base_branch> <old_base_branch> <branch_to_rebase>`

In your case, the command may look something like:

`git rebase --onto main_branch2 <hash_of_commit_at_base_of_main_branch2> feature_branch2`

This will checkout `main_branch2` and one by one apply the commits from `feature_branch2` on top of it. You can then merge `feature_branch2` in to `main_branch2`.

Is that along the lines of what you want to achieve? It's hard to know for sure without a diagram of the current state of the branches!

Comment: Yeah, I looked over for `--onto` parameter, but I'm not sure how it will help me actually. The thing is that the merge commit from branch `feature_branch1` is already in `feature_branch2` when I'm creating it. Now I want to merge just `feature_branch2` to `main_branch2`, but without this merge commit from `feature_branch1`. The graph above illustrates that actually.